# How to add new listener in the best way?

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework

I have project on ZF 1.x and I want to use EventDispatcher Symfony component.
I have 2 services User and Topic. After success user authentication I need to activate user's topics. So I create Event - AuthenticationEvent and fire event after authentication in User service like this

```
$dispatcher->dispatch('user.authentication.success', new AuthenticationEvent($user));
```

But where do I need to add listener? This code looks like

```
$listener = new TopicListener();
$dispatcher->addListener('user.authentication.success', array($listener, 'onAuthenticationAction'));
```

I had method authenticate in User service and there were code lines which were calling method activate($user) to activate topics in success case of authentication. Whereupon I had coupling between User and Topic service. That why I decided to use EventDispatcher.

So where is the best place for adding listeners? In some bootstrap part of code?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know ZF.
But you must add listener before dispatch event.

Has "bootsrap" file? Add listener there (or in the front controller).

Comment: I wanted to add there but I will add redundant listeners or I can link to controller name?

Comment: Event can dispatched not only in controller (in command for example). Add listener in the "bootstrap". This is not an expensive operation.